# Finding my mistake - residue

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm trying to find the residue of
$$g\left(z\right)=\frac{z}{\left(e^{iz}+1\right)^{2}}$$

around $-\pi$.
I was able to write:

$$g\left(z\right)=\frac{1}{\left(z+\pi\right)^{2}}\left(\frac{z+\pi}{\left(-i-\frac{z+\pi}{2}+...\right)^{2}}-\frac{\pi}{\left(-i-\frac{z+\pi}{2}+...\right)^{2}}\right)$$
So I suppose it is a pole of order 2. That means
$$Res\left(g,-\pi\right)=\lim_{z\to-\pi}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{z+\pi}{\left(-i-\frac{z+\pi}{2}+...\right)^{2}}-\frac{\pi}{\left(-i-\frac{z+\pi}{2}+...\right)^{2}}\right)$$
So I seem to get $-1$, although in a wolfram calculator I get $-1-i\pi$. What have I done wrong?
*Maybe I have to rethink changing the limit and the derivative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.  We need to differentiate and then take the limit.  To carry out the evaluation of the limit we proceed as follows.

We begin with $$e^{iz}+1=-\left(i(z+\pi)-\frac12(z+\pi)^2+\dots) \right)$$

where "$+\dots$" means "$+O(z+\pi)^3$."

Then, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{z\to-\pi}\frac{d}{dz}\frac{z(z+\pi)^2}{(e^{iz}+1)^2}&=\lim_{z\to -\pi}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{z}{\left(i-\frac12(z+\pi)+\dots) \right)^2}\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{z\to -\pi}\left(\frac1{\left(i-\frac12(z+\pi)+\dots) \right)^2}-\frac{2z\left(\frac12+O(z+\pi)\right)}{\left(i-\frac12(z+\pi)+\dots) \right)^3}\right)\\\\
&=\frac1{i^2}-\frac{\pi}{(i)^3}\\\\
&=-1-i\pi
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Answer (score 1):

You have$$(e^{iz}+1)^2=-(z+\pi)^2-i(z+\pi)^2+\cdots$$and therefore$$\frac z{(e^{iz}+1)^2}=\frac1{(z+\pi)^2}\cdot\frac z{-1-i(z+\pi)+\cdots}.$$If $g(z)=\frac z{-1-i(z+\pi)+\cdots}$ then $g'(-\pi)=-1-\pi i$ indeed.